# How to know if a program was opened with admin permission?

Tags: python

I have a Python program that opens a socket that communicates with a program on
a remote computer.
I want to check if the program on the remote computer was opened with admin permissions.
I have tried to look on-line, with no success.

Comment: it might be possible to see which user the process is running as but more info is need. What OS are you running on the remote computer?

Comment: you will try something that needs admin, and it will respond with failure due to reason X or it works.

Comment: try : `ps aux | grep program_name` from command line (i-e shell, not) (For linux or OSX). For windows, perhaps you could try ctrl+alt+del to open task manager? (not sure though).

Comment: How do i know a failure occured?

Answer (score 0):

This depends heavily on what the remote program *is*, and what other access you have to the server. The most reliable way would be to query the program so that it tells you its permissions - how to do this, and even whether it is actually possible, depends on what queries it supports and what responses it gives. If that isn't possible, you may be able to ask other processes on the server about it - for example, if you have shell access, you could try parsing the output of `ps aux` or locating information under `/proc`. But that has potential to be quite brittle, and also comes with a raft of security issues - you would give shell and possibly admin to every person who runs your script.

You should probably reconsider what you are trying to do with this information - there is probably a better way to solve the problem than inspecting the privileges of remote services. You've said that the process is an rpyc instance that gives you access to some Python module. Presumably, some of its functions are unavailable if it isn't running with enough permissions - in this case, the most Pythonic solution is to do exactly what you would do were it a local script: try to do whatever it is you need to do, and be prepared to handle a failure. This would usually involve a try/except block like this:

```
try:
    privileged_operation()
except PermissionError:
    # Handle the problem
```

You would need to consult the module's documentation, or play around with it a bit, to find out the exact error that it gives you here.

Comment: I am using an rpyc to communicate with the remote comuter. I already have some api that alows me to move files to the desitnation computer. Is there a way which is not platform depndent?

Comment: What do you need to *do* that requires admin? But as I say, it depends on the thing that you are running - rpyc appears to just give you remote access to an arbitrary Python module, so what you can do depends on what that module provides. Do you control that module, or the server in general?

Comment: I don't control the module in the sever side. I have some api thah alows me to run some process on the server though.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what the module is and what you're trying to do, it's hard to give detailed advice, but see my updated answer for what I think is the best that can be done without more details.

Comment: What inofrmation is needed? i have a client and sever that communicate with rpyc. I have complete control over the client. I can copy files to some admin permissions libary, but that is quick and dirthy.

Comment: The exact details of the modules you are able to run, especially which particular things you need to use for what you are ultimately trying to do.